Alphanumeric String Comparison In PHP
I am unable to understand how does PHP compare an alphanumeric string.
php > var_dump("222" < "30");
bool(false)

php > var_dump("222a" < "30");
bool(true)

The first comparison makes sense, but what's happening in the second one ? how is it comparing last two digits from 222a with 30 ?
Thank You.

The second comparison is lexicographic (aka dictionary order).

This first one only makes sense if you assume that these strings are converted to numbers. So, the number 222 is not smaller than 30. Since there's a letter in the second one, it cannot be a number, so it stays a string. If you look at an ASCII table you can see that a "2" comes before a "3" character, and therefore "222a" comes before "30". They will be compared as strings, not as numbers.

@KIKOSoftware, thanks for the answer, okay now it makes sense, I was thinking the other way around, so when comparing strings, it compares only the first character from both the strings and decides, correct ?

Don't you know what "dictionary order" means? I know that dictionaries are now things from the past, but still...

Yes, Olivier is right, when comparing strings, that aren't numbers, "dictionary order" is used. That's however not restricted to the first character only. Sure, when comparing "ab" to "cd" it only need to check the first characters to decide the comparison, but when comparing "abcdefg" and "abceefg" it needs to look at the first four characters to decide which is "smaller". Just like you would do when you look up a word in a paper dictionary.

@Olivier, no I don't, not everyone is Olivier. Thanks for the explanation though, it helped.

@KIKOSoftware, thanks for the detailed answer, understood now, so basically if the first characters are different, it answers. Otherwise it moves to the second character to decide.

Its very simple.
First case, since both the string consists of numbers, PHP treats them as number and compares them.
But as soon as there is an alphabet in one of the string, php treats them as string.,
